# Grails secure URL's using get form search

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a Grails application using Spring Security.

This application is basically a content management system, so it is a CRUD.

My URL's access are basically formatted as follows:

```
/$controller/$action/$id
```

This is where encounters problems. That occurs in a controller, for example, to change a user I have the following URL:

```
/user/update/1
```

And into the controller I have the following code:

```
def update(Long id) {
    def user = User.get(id);
    [user: user]
}
```

That's the problem. If the user change the (id) directly without checking if the user id in request is correct, anyone can surf the users of my system. Now i have a big problem.

The solution that I thought would be to create a unique hash for each registration system, which would hinder the user to understand that, for example, the ID 1 has the hash 123aabbCCDD, for example.

But i have a lot of registers and many domains in the system, and i don't know if this is   the best solution.

I need help to know, for example, using the spring security, I can do this kind of thing.

I tried to find solutions to the issue but I'm not sure by what words to search, so if there is already a question like mine, put the link in comments please.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad, but "checking if the user id in request is correct" is your key. What defines that will define how you solve this problem. It could be a simple as a filter that inspects the parameters or something as complex as Spring Security ACL. It all depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I didn't know the ACL exists. I'm reading now about that.
Sorry if the question is pretty broad, but i don't know how to be more specific about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joshua points out, if this is a general problem where you need to limit which users (or which roles) can perform particular actions, the spring-security-acl plugin will help. But that can be tedious to work with because you typically need to model things in a fine-grained way, and you end up with a *lot* of ACL data in the db.

But if you only want to restrict users to being able to edit themselves, just don't pass the user id. You already know who the user is if the action requires authentication. If that's the case, change the action to something like

```
def springSecurityService

def update() {
   [user: springSecurityService.currentUser]
}
```

A related workflow that can often avoid using ACLs is allowing a user to edit something that they own, e.g. a `CreditCard`. Assuming you have `static hasMany = [creditCards: CreditCard]` in the `User` class and `static belongsTo = [user: User]` (or just `User user`), then you can allow the form to send the credit card id, but you just need to use a modified query, e.g.

```
def springSecurityService

def update(Long id) {
   def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
   def card = CreditCard.findByIdAndUser(id, user)
   [creditCard: card]
}
```

The final SQL query will look something like `select ... from credit_card where id=? and user_id=?`, which has a big security advantage over the SQL for a `get()` call which would be `select ... from credit_card where id=?`. A malicious user can still try to send any id they want, but since the `where` clause checks both the id and the user foreign key, if they're not logged in as the card owner, the finder will return null and you can treat that as a mistake or a hack and not allow access.

Note that the hash approach you described isn't very secure - it's just "security by obscurity". If each user's hash is constant, it's not difficult to find out what a user's hash is and forge a request (e.g. a coworker can just look at another's monitor and see the url in their browser).

Comment: Ok. Now i understand the real use for ACL. The only problem to use the plugin is my app using grails 2.2.3 with Acegi plugin, and i need to upgrade this. The biggest problem, at this time and i don't see how to be more effective, is the application  running, and i have a lot of controllers. It's no magic for that, i need to change all controller manually. @Burt thanks again.

Comment: I found this tutorial, http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=287, using acegi, that's the actual plugin i'm using in my app, have any resource coded for acegi 5.3.x?

Comment: Acegi? You need to upgrade today. It's nearly 2016.

Comment: *Sorry if my question is dumb, but why? . I'm using grails 2.2.3. How necessary is to upgrade Grails version? Because in grails plugins page the version compatible of spring security plugin is 2.3.0 > *. There's another version of SS compatible with this version? Thanks again @Burt.

Comment: Upgrading Grails can be a lot of work, depending on the size of the delta between versions and whether you used features that changed a lot. But it's often worth the effort so you can take advantage of important fixes, performance boosts, new features, etc. But using old security libraries and plugins is potentially very risky to you and your users if there are significant fixes or changes that you're missing. You can use version 2.0-RC3 which requires Grails 2.0+, and upgrade to RC5 or 2.0 final when it's released, or 3.0.x if you upgrade to Grails 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarify @Burt.